# Tomcat's logs is empty after rotating - AWS EC2 - Tomcat 8

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, console, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Every Tomcat's logs is empty. When I access EC2 with console on the /var/log/tomcat8 dir, every log file is empty with 0kb.

I already tried to change the **logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.tomcat8.conf**, but without success.

This is the entire **logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.tomcat8.conf** file as I already tried to change.

```
/var/log/tomcat8/* {
size 10M
rotate 5
missingok
compress
notifempty
dateext
dateformat %s
olddir /var/log/tomcat8/rotated
}
```

This is how Tomcat's log file look:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat     0 Jul 18 00:01 catalina.2019-07-17.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat     0 Jul 18 17:01 catalina.2019-07-18.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat     0 Jul 19 19:01 catalina.2019-07-19.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `rotated` subdirectory for .gz files with the same filename as a prefix. E.g., `catalina.2019-07-17*.gz`